# Prova that $(\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^N}),d)$ is a complete metrical space.

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, complete-spaces

Where $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Space of Rapidly Decreasing Functions, i. e., $f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ if, only if, $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$ \sup_{|\alpha|\leq j}\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R^N}}(1+|x|^2)^j|(D_{\alpha}f)(x)|<+\infty,$$ for all $j=0,1,2,\dots$ and
$$d(f,g)=\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^j}\cdot \dfrac{\rho_j(f-g)}{1+\rho_j(f-g)}$$ with $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\in(\mathbb{N_0})^N$, $$\rho_j(f):=\sup_{|\alpha|\leq j}\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R^N}}(1+|x|^2)^j|(D_{\alpha}f)(x)|\quad\text{ and }\quad D_{\alpha}=\left(\dfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)^{\alpha_1}\dots \left(\dfrac{1}{i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_N}\right)^{\alpha_N}.$$

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: You have to understand that this question is *enormous*. The metric in question is quite complicated. Proving the three axioms, especially the triangle inequality, is chore enough. Then we need to show completeness, which involves 1. constructing a supposed limit function from a Cauchy sequence, 2. showing the function belongs to the space (and not just *infinitely* differentiable, but involves showing countable inequalities), then 3. showing that this supposed limit is indeed the limit. There are *so many steps*!

Comment: So, with that in mind, it's kind of unfair to just ask us the question like this, with no idea what you can and can't do for yourself. Can you prove it's a metric? If you can't, then this would be a fair question to start off with. If you can, then tell us so that we don't tell you what you already know. This is why we require you to provide context with problems, not just state them. We don't like repeating what you already know, any more than you like reading it!

Comment: First show that $\rho_j$ is a semi-norm and $\rho_0$ is a norm. From this you can deduce that $d$ is a metric. For completeness, pick a sequence and use $\rho_0$ to deduce that the sequence converges pointwise. Then use the other semi-norms go show that this candidate is in $C^\infty$. You will need a lemma that tells you if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and $f_n'$ converges uniformly to $g$, then $f$ is differentiable and $f'=g$. Then you can use again the semi-norms to conclude that $f$ is actually a Schwartz function.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I do not know where to start

Comment: @TheoBendit Prove that d is a metric is not necessary. This we can assume as true

Comment: @Rodolfo I've already told you how to proceed. Which part is not clear to you?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven yea! my comment was for your first response. I appreciate the interaction, thank you! I am trying based on your answer. In case I have doubts I will contact in here

Comment: @Rodolfo Best would be if you write your answer up below. Then all the people in the future can see the correct answer and you can get feedback from the community :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Of course my friend! I will do that